# Cant listen for server events using publishUpdate with sails js

Tags: angularjs, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

Im trying to publishUpdate some data from the server in order to listen for user/profile creation but im not able to listen to those events in the client using Angular. Is it possible im missing something here? Or maybe something wrong im doing?

```
// UserController

saveUser: function(req, res) {
 User.create({name: req.param('name'), profile: {aboutMe: req.param('about'), gender: req.param('gender')}})
  .exec(function(err, user) {
    Profile
      .findOneById(user.profile)
      .exec(function(err, profile) {
       profile.user = user.id;
       profile.save(function(error, saved){
         if (error) return res.badRequest('Error.');  
         if (saved) res.json(saved);

         Profile.publishUpdate(saved.id, saved);
       });
     });
   });
}

// Client Angular

$scope.send = createUser;

listenProfile();

function createUser() {        
 var obj = {
   name: $scope.name,
   about: $scope.profile.about,
   gender: $scope.profile.gender

  User.create(obj).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data); // Data displayed correctly
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

function listenProfile() {
  io.socket.on('profile',function(data){
    console.log(data);  //Nothing happens?             
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't 'Profile'?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to a capital P:

```
function listenProfile() {
  io.socket.on('Profile',function(data){
    console.log(data);  //Nothing happens?             
  });
};
```

Comment: It is not related. Same thing in both cases

Comment: Same thing in both cases?  I don't know what you mean.  publishUpdate emits the model name as the event. The model name is Profile, not profile. Which one does it emit?

Comment: Check http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.io.js/io.socket.on.html?q=notes

Comment: Ok that's what I was asking.

Comment: You have confirmed that saveUser is firing?

Comment: have you setup a socket connection between sails and angular?

Comment: Sure.. is firing like a charm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76665/discussion-between-tpie-and-user1763639).

Answer (score 0):

I think that are missing "suscribe" to your model... for example

```
Profile.subscribe(req.socket, data);
```

And linked to your app via GET.

```
io.socket.get("/profile",function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```